# Chocolate bars - Actual shelflife vs expiration date

Tags: storage-lifetime, chocolate, storage

The owner of a local chocolate store made me an offer I actually can't refuse: For a price that's really a bargain, I get one bar of every bar chocolate he as on stock - that would be about 40 bars.

I know how to store chocolate for baking (mostly Callebaut callets) and from my own experience I can tell that when stored in an airtight container in a dry, dark and cool place away from things with a strong smell (e.g. coffee) most chocolate can be used even after expiration date (only for private use of course).

But what about chocolate bars - is it the same?

I don't care about blooming, I just don't want the the chocolate goes bad before I can try them.

Comment: It depends on the mixed-in ingredients, but for dark chocolate you should easily get a year in a cool, dry, dark place, unless there are quite perishable mix-ins.  Milk chocolate is somewhat more perishable, but will still last for months, again depending on the mixins.

Comment: If you're okay with a certain amount of quality loss in favor of food safety you can always freeze a number of them for indefinite safe storage.

Comment: Do you know anything about the filling?

Comment: Yes, it varies. Some bars are plain dark or milk chocolate, others have stuff like caramel, sesame or nuts in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're referring to plain chocolate bars, I say go for it.  Plain chocolate (unsweetened, milk, or dark) lasts, if unopened, for years.  The most that will happen is that the outside turns whitish in color, but this does not affect taste or quality.  If there is any sort of filling, though, I, personally, would not eat it more than a month or two past the expiration date.